# Nanomsg message encryption between communicating nodes

Tags: c, encryption, messaging, nanomsg

I am new to messaging world and started using [Nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/) library in my application. I want to know whether the messages are encrypted by default between the server and the client by the [Nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/) library. If not, how can I add encryption to secure the messages between the communicating nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payload of the message is not encrypted. You can add encryption and decryption for payload into the client and server.  A very simple encryption is described here [Simply encrypt a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622617/simply-encrypt-a-string-in-c)